# Spring JPA data removed after shutdown of application

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

i have an application thats build on Spring boot, using JPA repositories on HSQL database.

Problem is that while application is running, I create an entity,and it's persisted correctly to database(can be seen in database manager). But after application shutdown from eclipse, all data is removed;

Saving is performed like this

```
@Service
public class NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

    public void notifyRefreshArticles(){
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        notification.setNotificationSeverity(NotificationSeverity.NORMAL);
        notification.setNotificationType(NotificationType.REFRESH_ARTICLES);

        notificationRepository.save(notification);
    }
}
```

I pretty sure its configuration issue,but with spring boot basically only configuration that i have is this configuration file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/rr_app_database
spring.datasource.username=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Show your datasource. It looks like you are using hsqldb, which usually is used in memory. If that is the case, of course it will die when you shutdown the application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364171/hsql-question-on-data-being-saved check out this link. This might be a similar issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you have hbm2ddl text somewhere in your configuration properties. It should be set to `update` or `none`, apparently you might have `create-drop`.

Comment: this is the right answer,i've add property spring.datasource.hbm2ddl.auto=update and it works fine

Comment: Glad i was able to help

Comment: That property might be spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update also.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a local filename in application.properties data source URL:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/username/testedb
```

You can remove the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property as Spring Boot detects it by URL property.

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties files if there exists a configuration line as below

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Just remove it or change to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you insert the data within a `@Test`, it's rolled back by default.
2. Your database might get dropped, if you restart the application, like LearningPhase suggested.
3. The `insert` is never really committed - because it's outside of an transaction or because an `Exception` is thrown and not handeled within the transaction.